# Git detached head state

Tags: angularjs, git

I'm going through the [tutorial for angularjs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00).  In step 0 of the tutorial it instructs me to run:

`git checkout -f step-0`

When I ran this I got "You are in 'detached HEAD' state" which I take to mean that I just created a new feature branch called "step-0" that did not previously exist. Then I reloaded my web page and saw that all the cool stuff from the master branch is now gone.  Instead I get this basic page that says "Nothing here yet!".

Now this is all correct behavior.  My question is why did `git checkout` change the state of my code?

I could understand if the branch existed and I switched branches then yea that would change my code.  But in this case it looks like the branch does not exist and I don't see a branch by the name "step-0" on [github](https://github.com/angular/angular-phonecat).

So in my mind I just branched off Master and created a new feature branch.  Any changes in code don't make sense to me in this case.

What happened?

Comment: Could it be that `step-0` is a tag, rather than a branch? **Edit** Yep, it's a tag.

Comment: @Biffen - Yes!  There is a tag by that name.  This is my first run-in with tags so I'm not sure what they are all about.

Comment: See [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) and [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag).

Comment: Basically tag is a fancy name of commit #hash. So it's like you are going to that #commit. You can get back to your original codebase you cloned with git checkout master, anytime anyplace (master is name of branch).

Note that branch names are basically fancy names for commit hashes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "detached HEAD" message means that you're not at the tip of *any* branch.  You've gone back to an earlier commit on the master branch, but you haven't created a new branch that begins there.

You got there by switching to the "step-0" tag.  A [tag](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) in Git is basically an alias for a commit ID:  "step-0" refers to the commit `96a9b5b7fa5e5667e099d25c20a4bb19992c0f72`.  Tags are commonly used for naming releases (e.g. a "v1.0" tag on the revision that was released as version 1.0), but in this case they're just used to make it easy to switch to specific revisions as you follow the tutorial.  A branch isn't needed because you aren't going to be committing a divergent set of changes from there.

Branches and tags are similar in that they're both names that refer to commits.  The difference is that a branch *changes* as you create new commits — the branch name is updated to refer to the new commit ID each time — whereas tags are typically used to record points in history that don't change, such as the contents of a specific released version.  (It's possible to change a tag, but only in the same sense that it's possible to change the history of a branch:  if you've already pushed the tag to others, you'll have to ask them to delete it and pull the new one instead.  You can't force tag changes on others.)

If you *want* to start a new branch from the commit you've just moved to, you can do so:  `git checkout -b my-branch`.

Comment: *A tag in Git is basically an alias for a commit ID*. This description doesn't really suit *annotated* tags, though.